# load images from closest/fastest server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

If I have identical sets of images for a website on different servers in different countries, and when a user opens the website, that the images are downloaded to their computer from the closest/fastest location to them? Making the website load faster.

Comment: It sounds like you should look in to using a company which provides a geolocated CDN service. Also note that you haven't asked a question here, and if the next question is 'how do I do this', then your question is too broad.

Comment: thanks for your comment and suggestion, Rory.